# Having troubles with file_exists and is_file

Tags: php, file-exists

I've prepared this bit of code, and as you can see I've commented out my problem area

```
//prepare the image file path that includes the isbn in the file name
    $imageFilePath = '"./data/images/' . $book[0] . '.jpg"';

            // Debugging
    // $var = "==>" . file_exists($imageFilePath) . "<==is it true?";
    // $str .= $var;
    // //tests if file is NOT there, if it isn't the imagepath reflects the default image
    // if (file_exists($imageFilePath) == false){

        // $imageFilePath = '"./data/images/default.jpg"';
    // }
```

My image path variable works like a charm, now I want to use a default image if the file doesn't exist.
When the if statement is uncommented all my images become a default image

I've tried is_file and file_exists, to no avail. You can also see that I try to capture the result with the $var variable, there is no space between the ==> and the <==.

I've just started learning programming, and in general I am usually able to debug with an echo here and there or by using the internet. I can't find a solution.

All help is much appreciated, and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that

```
$imageFilePath = "somethingToCheck";
$imageFilePathDefault = "somethingDefault";
$imageFilePath = file_exists($imageFilePath) ? $imageFilePath : $imageFilePathDefault;
```

For `file_exists` explaination and argument accepted, please take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

For the third line of code, let's interpret it like:

```
if(file_exists($imageFilePath))
 $imageFilePath = $imageFilePath; //confirm that is valid
else
 $imageFilePath = $imageFilePathDefault; //change to default
```

**Edit** after your edit, i suggest also to remove double quotas from your path

Comment: @carlitto : the first is more compact and elegant ;)

Comment: can you explain the ? and the : usage, I haven't seen that yet

Comment: i always want to know why i code what i'm adding, instead of copy pasting

Comment: @carlitto : i've explained it. the third line of code is exactly the same as the second code's block. So the leftmost operand before `?` is evaluated (the leftmost, except variable assignment of course!). If is `true` then the statement after `?` is evaluated and assigned. If is `false` then the statement after `:` is evaluated and assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the double quotes:

```
$imageFilePath = './data/images/' . $book[0] . '.jpg';
```

Comment: Yes, and if that doesn't work, your file path is probably just wrong. In that case, try putting a hard file path into your code, for example `/home/user/data/images/book.jpg` and see whether that works. Also, for debugging purposes, you can use `var_dump` or `print_r`; that'll get you more useful information than trying to echo boolean values.

Comment: `print __DIR__ . '/data/images/' . $book[0] . '.jpg';` to see where PHP is looking (also see the include paths).

Comment: Thx, the double quotes weren't the problem, but i'll look into the var_dump. I just discovered the print_r today so it's not second nature yet. Thx for your help